# NGINX + HHVM + SOAP Chunked response

Tags: php, soap, nginx, hhvm

Seems that NGINX wont pass the correct HTTP protocol to HHVM backend.

Here the tests I've done:

If the client send a HTTP/1.1 request (non chunked) NGINX pass it to the HHVM backend and the correct response come back to the client

```
(client)                           (server backend)
HTTP/1.1(non chunked)  -> NGINX ->    HHVM
                                       |
                                       v
(HTTP/1.1 200)         <- NGINX <- (non chunked response)
```

If the client send a HTTP/1.1 request (chuncked), the server produce a chunked reponse, but NGINX fire this log message

```
upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, request: "POST /soap HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/hhvm/sock:"
```

and return a 502 (bad gateway) response

```
(client)                           (server backend)
HTTP/1.1(chunked)      -> NGINX ->    HHVM
                                       |
                                       v
(HTTP/1.1 502)         <- NGINX <- (chunked response)
```

Why I got a 502 from NGINX using chunked response?

Is there something wrong with hhvm/fastcgi/hhvm config?

I double checked that backend give a correct 1/1 response :(

I've a scenario with:

```
NGINX:nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
HHVM: HipHop VM 3.6.1 (rel)
```

The NGINX config is

```
server {
   listen      80;
   server_name xxxxx;

   root /usr/share/nginx/web;
   include hhvm.conf;


   location / {
       # try to serve file directly, fallback to rewrite
       try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
   }

   location @rewriteapp {
       # rewrite all to app.php
       rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
   }

   location ~ ^/(app|app_dev|app_benchmark|app_logall|config)\.php(/|$) {
       fastcgi_keep_conn on;
       #fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
       fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/hhvm/sock;
       fastcgi_index  index.php;
       fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

       fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
       fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;
       fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
       fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
       fastcgi_read_timeout 240;
       fastcgi_intercept_errors on;

       include        fastcgi_params;

   }
}
```

Comment: What is your question/desired behaviour?

Comment: thanks for the note.. I've edited the question :)

Comment: I had a look at [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/430647/chunked-response-in-nginx-not-working) but the solution proposed there is to update the nginx (obviously the version I'm using is > 1.1.4 as explained [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/faq/chunked_encoding_from_backend.html) )